# Reducing table width

Tags: tables, width

I have the following table: [image: table] It is very wide. How can I reduce its width?

```
\begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \sisetup{table-format=1.3e-2, table-alignment=center, tight-spacing}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
        \small
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X cSS[table-format=1.5] SS[table-format=1.5]}
            \toprule
            ID & {ABC Dataset Name} & {$X^2$ (XXX)} & {$Y^2$ (YYYY)} \\ [0.5ex]
            \midrule
            DS1 & ABCDE ABCD & 0.0243 & 0.2039 \\
            DS2 & ABCD       & 0.0594 & 0.0015 \\
            DS3 & XYZE       & 0.2318 & 0.7709 \\
            DS4 & ABC ABC    & 0.1555 & 0.5613 \\ [1ex]
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{11 my caption}
\label{table:3}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}` perhaps, depending on the content.... that is what the 1st argument of the `tabularx` environment is meant for: Specification of table width, from which the space for the `X` columns is calculated. Please don't post such fragments only. Using `\centering` in a `\linewidth` wide table is also pretty useless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

[image]

- for your table i wouldn't use `tabularx` environment, in your case is better `tabular`
- you have defined 6 columns but you use only four. in mwe below i remove superfluous columns

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]}}
        \toprule
        ID  & ABC Dataset Name  & {$X^2$ (XXX)} & {$Y^2$ (YYYY)} \\
        \midrule
        DS1 & ABCDE ABCD        & 0.0243        & 0.2039 \\
        DS2 & ABCD              & 0.0594        & 0.0015 \\
        DS3 & XYZE              & 0.2318        & 0.7709 \\
        DS4 & ABC ABC           & 0.1555        & 0.5613 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{11 my caption}
\label{table:3}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico, thank you ... is to early (for today) to me to observe, that op column definition not complain with numbers in them :-). corrected! happy new year to you too!